# Use Azure DevOps pipeline variable for resource repositories name in azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a shared *Azure pipeline yaml* definition with the purpose to define one CodeAnalysis pipeline per repository.
How can I define the repository name dynamically?

I tried with `name: '$(projectName)'` which leads to the error:

> The repository $(projectName) in project 8ab9d22b-6819-483b-829d-******* could not be retrieved. Verify the name and credentials being used.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: codeAnalysisRepo
      type: git
      name: shared/codeanalysis
  
    - repository: SourceRepo
      type: git
      name: '$(projectName)'
  
jobs:
  - job: 'BackendCodeAnalysis'
    pool:
      name: '$(AgentPool)'

steps:
  - checkout: SourceRepo
    clean: true
        
  - template: sonarqube_msbuild_prepare.yml@codeAnalysisRepo
    parameters:
      projectKey: '$(project)'
      projectName: '$(project)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "build DestRepo"
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/**/*.csproj'
      configuration: Release

  - template: sonarqube_execute.yml@codeAnalysisRepo
```

It works when I hardcode the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, set parameter and variable is not supported in resources -> repositories.

A work around for this, you could set this at the checkout step. Here is s sample: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout). Please note that, the repos should be in the same organization.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Repo1
      type: git
      name: Artifacts/Repo1

  
jobs:
  - job: 'BackendCodeAnalysis'
    pool:
      vmimage: windows-latest

    steps:
      - checkout: git://$(projectName)
        clean: true
```

For your demand, you could create a suggestion ticket via: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem)

Comment: could you please provide more info ? I use `checkout: git://$(System.TeamProject)/$(pullRequestRepositoryName)`,  the var `pullRequestRepositoryName` is computed dynamically in the `script` task just before the `checkout` task. I got the error: `TF200016: The following project does not exist: $(System.TeamProject). Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server`.

Comment: we're having this issue as well.  has anyone already submitted a suggestion ticket for it? I cant find one on the dev community page